# Partial match two strings with wildcard operators both ways

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have two lists of property names. Sometimes a name in List A has extra characters; sometimes List B has the extra characters. I want to pull associated data from a column in the tab with List A and add it to the tab with List B, by property name.

A few examples are:

| List A | List B |
| --- | --- |
| AMLI Riverside | AMLI on Riverside |
| Adam Hats Downtown Lofts | Adam Hats Lofts |
| Atlantic at Kessler Park | Atlantic at Kessler Park, The |

My current thought for a solution is to split by word in List A and add wildcard operators inside Query with the Like operator in the Where clause. I think I would need to do so before, after, between each substring. I haven't tested it yet, but something like this:

`=query(A2:A,"Select _ where _ like '%AMLI%Riverside%'")`

And then would need to also build in the string splitting, presumably with SPLIT around " ".

Before I go down this rabbit hole - am I missing a better solution? There are ~650 properties in List A and ~2000 properties in List B, so would prefer not to check manually.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). This is not a trivial problem, and you may need _fuzzy matching_ to make it work. Choose **Add-ons > Get add-ons** and search for `fuzzy` to review possible solutions.

Comment: HI and welcome. I agree 100% with @doubleunary - this is not trivial. I can imagine a user-developed script based on the javascript method `indexOf`. But it is moot whether the development time could be justified versus buying/using a fuzzy logic add-on.